# Creating jars for Maven repository, how?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, javadoc

Googled this question but no straight answer was found sadly.

So, I have a Maven project. I want to upload my release to Maven Central Repository. This means I need to create 3-4 jar files:

1. Compiled source jar
2. Javadoc jar
3. Source code jar
4. Tests jar (optional)

How can I create all these jars? Add some configuration to POM?

BTW, I am using latest Netbeans IDE, but this shouldn't matter :)

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

So this is my POM:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>antlr</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>antlr4</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: How you pom Looks like at the Moment?

Comment: @Jens edited my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven can create these jars for your. Next to 1,2,3,4 you will also need to sign your release artifacts. To get the artifact into maven central I would advise you to read:

1. The [official Maven guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html) to get your artifact into maven central
2. The [guide](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html) from the Open Source Sonatype repository. It contains all the information you will need to know.

With regards to your pom.xml you can add a separate release profile, which builds all these artifacts for you.

Just add the following profile to your pom.xml

```
<profile>
  <id>release</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-source-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Now when you want to create the release you can just call:

```
mvn clean install -Prelease
```

and it will create all the required artifacts.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Will give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [guide](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/choosing-your-coordinates.html) and [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html). You need to raise a ticket for a mirror repository of your choice, then you need to use additionally plugins for signing jar, generating documents, adding source and doing remote deployment for you.

Comment: I think you also need to prove ownership of the domain which you use in the pom